# Беспорядок с меткой [отображения]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [отображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) (обратите внимание, "я" в конце) чаще всего используют в качестве "отображени**е**", только первый вопрос про отображения, то есть [map](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map). Я считаю что надо создать метку "отображени**е**" и поставить на эти вопросы.

У нас принято синонимизировать метки в пользу русских, но здесь думаю уместнее будет сделать наоборот.

А метку [отображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) думаю вообще удалить.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем тут тонкая разница? "Отображения" может быть только про математические отображения, тогда как "Отображение" - либо про них, либо про вывод чего-то на экран? Учитывая всего 7 вопросов в метке, вряд ли это большая проблема.